# Prove or refute that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2+A\varphi(n)+B}$ will be irrational for some choice of integers $A,B\geq 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, totient-function

We denote the Euler's totient function as $\varphi(n)$ for integers $n\geq 1$,  that is a multiplicative function that counts the number of integers $1\leq k\leq n$  up to the given integer n that satisfy $\gcd(k,n)=1$.

I'm curious about if one can to find fixed integers $a\geq 1$ and $b\geq 1$ such that we can prove or refute that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2+a\varphi(n)+b}$$
is a rational number.

> **Question.** Choose some fixed integers $A\geq 1$ and $B\geq 1$. Can you prove that your series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2+A\varphi(n)+B}\tag{1}$$
>   is a rational number? Or well can (you refute it) you prove that $(1)$ is irrational? **Many thanks.**

Because I think that this question is very difficult **only is required what work can be done about it**, and after that there are some answers I should accept one.